# Sending image file data from the front end to the backend

Tags: node.js, file, image-uploading, cloudinary

is there a way I can send an image file from the front end to the backend? I need to upload the image selected in the form to the cloudinary cloud platform.

Accessing the file input with `req.body` does not help and gives me an error saying `no such file or directory open`.

If I add `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, and then on my backend do a `req.on('data', (data)=> {console.log(data.toString)})` and then perform an upload to cloudinary, it fails and gives me the following error:  `Error: Path must be a string without null bytes`

This is my form:

```
<form method="post" action="/submitArticle" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="file">
      <label class="file-label">
        <input class="file-input" type="file" name="image">
        <span class="file-cta">
          <span class="file-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
          </span>
          <span class="file-label">
            Choose a file…
          </span>
        </span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label class="title is-4">Title</label>
      <div class="control">
        <input class="input" name="title" type="text" placeholder="Give your story a title...">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <label class="title is-4">Story</label>
      <div class="control">
        <textarea class="textarea" name="story" rows="7" placeholder="Tell your story here..."></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field is-grouped is-grouped-right">
      <p class="control">
        <input class="button is-primary" type="submit">
        </input>
      </p>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Is there another way to send image data from the front end to the backend? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upload to Cloudinary, maybe you should consider using [Cloudinary Upload Widget](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget).

The widget supports uploading images directly from the browser to Cloudinary storage, without involving your servers in the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party library like [Dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) to upload image in the frontend and send it to the backend. Simple that's it